# Unable to make the table body scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please have a look at the below code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #table-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
#table-scroll {
  height:150px;
  overflow:auto;  
  margin-top:20px;
}
#table-wrapper table {
  width:100%;

}
#table-wrapper table * {
  background:yellow;
  color:black;
}
#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
  position:absolute;   
  top:-20px;
  z-index:2;
  height:20px;
  width:35%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="table-wrapper">
  <div style="height:200px; overflow:auto"> 
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span class="text">A</span></th>
                <th><span class="text">B</span></th>
                <th><span class="text">C</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr> <td>1, 0</td> <td>2, 0</td> <td>3, 0</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 1</td> <td>2, 1</td> <td>3, 1</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 2</td> <td>2, 2</td> <td>3, 2</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 3</td> <td>2, 3</td> <td>3, 3</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 4</td> <td>2, 4</td> <td>3, 4</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 5</td> <td>2, 5</td> <td>3, 5</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 6</td> <td>2, 6</td> <td>3, 6</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 7</td> <td>2, 7</td> <td>3, 7</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 8</td> <td>2, 8</td> <td>3, 8</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 9</td> <td>2, 9</td> <td>3, 9</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 10</td> <td>2, 10</td> <td>3, 10</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 11</td> <td>2, 11</td> <td>3, 11</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 12</td> <td>2, 12</td> <td>3, 12</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 13</td> <td>2, 13</td> <td>3, 13</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 14</td> <td>2, 14</td> <td>3, 14</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 15</td> <td>2, 15</td> <td>3, 15</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 16</td> <td>2, 16</td> <td>3, 16</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 17</td> <td>2, 17</td> <td>3, 17</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 18</td> <td>2, 18</td> <td>3, 18</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 19</td> <td>2, 19</td> <td>3, 19</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 20</td> <td>2, 20</td> <td>3, 20</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 21</td> <td>2, 21</td> <td>3, 21</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 22</td> <td>2, 22</td> <td>3, 22</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 23</td> <td>2, 23</td> <td>3, 23</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 24</td> <td>2, 24</td> <td>3, 24</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 25</td> <td>2, 25</td> <td>3, 25</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 26</td> <td>2, 26</td> <td>3, 26</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 27</td> <td>2, 27</td> <td>3, 27</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 28</td> <td>2, 28</td> <td>3, 28</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 29</td> <td>2, 29</td> <td>3, 29</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 30</td> <td>2, 30</td> <td>3, 30</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 31</td> <td>2, 31</td> <td>3, 31</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 32</td> <td>2, 32</td> <td>3, 32</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 33</td> <td>2, 33</td> <td>3, 33</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 34</td> <td>2, 34</td> <td>3, 34</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 35</td> <td>2, 35</td> <td>3, 35</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 36</td> <td>2, 36</td> <td>3, 36</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 37</td> <td>2, 37</td> <td>3, 37</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 38</td> <td>2, 38</td> <td>3, 38</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 39</td> <td>2, 39</td> <td>3, 39</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 40</td> <td>2, 40</td> <td>3, 40</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 41</td> <td>2, 41</td> <td>3, 41</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 42</td> <td>2, 42</td> <td>3, 42</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 43</td> <td>2, 43</td> <td>3, 43</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 44</td> <td>2, 44</td> <td>3, 44</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 45</td> <td>2, 45</td> <td>3, 45</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 46</td> <td>2, 46</td> <td>3, 46</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 47</td> <td>2, 47</td> <td>3, 47</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 48</td> <td>2, 48</td> <td>3, 48</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 49</td> <td>2, 49</td> <td>3, 49</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 50</td> <td>2, 50</td> <td>3, 50</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 51</td> <td>2, 51</td> <td>3, 51</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 52</td> <td>2, 52</td> <td>3, 52</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 53</td> <td>2, 53</td> <td>3, 53</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 54</td> <td>2, 54</td> <td>3, 54</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 55</td> <td>2, 55</td> <td>3, 55</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 56</td> <td>2, 56</td> <td>3, 56</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 57</td> <td>2, 57</td> <td>3, 57</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 58</td> <td>2, 58</td> <td>3, 58</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 59</td> <td>2, 59</td> <td>3, 59</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 60</td> <td>2, 60</td> <td>3, 60</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 61</td> <td>2, 61</td> <td>3, 61</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 62</td> <td>2, 62</td> <td>3, 62</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 63</td> <td>2, 63</td> <td>3, 63</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 64</td> <td>2, 64</td> <td>3, 64</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 65</td> <td>2, 65</td> <td>3, 65</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 66</td> <td>2, 66</td> <td>3, 66</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 67</td> <td>2, 67</td> <td>3, 67</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 68</td> <td>2, 68</td> <td>3, 68</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 69</td> <td>2, 69</td> <td>3, 69</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 70</td> <td>2, 70</td> <td>3, 70</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 71</td> <td>2, 71</td> <td>3, 71</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 72</td> <td>2, 72</td> <td>3, 72</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 73</td> <td>2, 73</td> <td>3, 73</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 74</td> <td>2, 74</td> <td>3, 74</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 75</td> <td>2, 75</td> <td>3, 75</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 76</td> <td>2, 76</td> <td>3, 76</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 77</td> <td>2, 77</td> <td>3, 77</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 78</td> <td>2, 78</td> <td>3, 78</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 79</td> <td>2, 79</td> <td>3, 79</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 80</td> <td>2, 80</td> <td>3, 80</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 81</td> <td>2, 81</td> <td>3, 81</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 82</td> <td>2, 82</td> <td>3, 82</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 83</td> <td>2, 83</td> <td>3, 83</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 84</td> <td>2, 84</td> <td>3, 84</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 85</td> <td>2, 85</td> <td>3, 85</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 86</td> <td>2, 86</td> <td>3, 86</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 87</td> <td>2, 87</td> <td>3, 87</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 88</td> <td>2, 88</td> <td>3, 88</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 89</td> <td>2, 89</td> <td>3, 89</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 90</td> <td>2, 90</td> <td>3, 90</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 91</td> <td>2, 91</td> <td>3, 91</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 92</td> <td>2, 92</td> <td>3, 92</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 93</td> <td>2, 93</td> <td>3, 93</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 94</td> <td>2, 94</td> <td>3, 94</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 95</td> <td>2, 95</td> <td>3, 95</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 96</td> <td>2, 96</td> <td>3, 96</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 97</td> <td>2, 97</td> <td>3, 97</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 98</td> <td>2, 98</td> <td>3, 98</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>1, 99</td> <td>2, 99</td> <td>3, 99</td> </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I was trying to create a HTML table, where the user can scroll the "body". However my attempt failed, the output I got is below.

[image]

That is weird, the titles of the table are not displayed properly, and they are out of alignment. I do not want to set any fixed sizes anyway, because users can resize the browser at anytime, who knows?

How can I fix this?

Comment: There was another answer here, where is it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this trouble by using `datatables`. Here is a link for an example: http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Answer (score 1):

```
tbody, tr, td, th { display: inline-block; }
tbody { max-height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; width: 100%; }
tr { width: 100%; } 
td, th { float: left; width: 33%; }
```

Adding that should be all you need to get your tbody scrolling vertically. This won't apply to IE9, however, where the tbody will render its full height instead.

I wouldn't get into absolute positioning of elements, as this will be unreliable if your table requires any responsive styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/q9mmq2er/1/

Comment: Hi, you mean remove the rest of the css?

Comment: You may be over-complicating things with the other stuff. Not sure how much of that CSS is tied to the greater styling vs. your attempts to get the scrolling working. But yeah, you shouldn't need absolute positioning to do this.

Comment: tried, didnt work. Can you please do some edit to my code or put a jsfiddle?

Comment: It is out of layout. Here is the image - https://www.dropbox.com/s/5y2h4b0oj811yku/issue.png?dl=0

Comment: Updated to include your CSS.

Comment: Did this do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I changed to make it work:

```
#table-wrapper table thead th {
    position:relative;
}

#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Problem was that you set a `top: -20px;` on `.text`

Comment: Hi, here, the table header does scroll.